# How to use iddata type structure

Tags: arrays, matlab, signal-processing, resampling

I want to resample an array of elements using the command `idresamp()`. The input arguments for `idresamp` function is an array `x`. So I should get the output as an array. However, I am getting a structure `iddata`. I don't know how to access the elements /result of the resampling. Can somebody please show how to access the resampled values? Thank you.

```
  x=rand(4000,1); %create some arbitrary data
  x_resamp =idresamp(x,2); %resampling factor is 2
```

Here `x_resamp` is of iddata type. So, I am unable to access the result. On clicking the variable `x_resamp` this is what I got

[image: img]

How does one access the resampled values (output). Where is the array? The next step is to calculate the power after resampling and hence I need to use the resampled values.

I am using Matlab R2018a.

Comment: Did you look through the documentation to [`iddata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ug/representing-time-and-frequency-domain-data-using-iddata-objects.html#responsive_offcanvas)? Alternatively, use [`resample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ref/resample.html), which returns a normal array.

Comment: The docs say to use `data.InputData` or `data.OutputData`, depending on which data you want to get out. It seems you have only output data in your object?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I looked into `resample` but could not understand what should be the value of the parameter if I want to resample by 2 as there are 2 arguments in this function. For the second comment, I only have output data in my object. So, what should I do?

Comment: In the example of `resample` th line `ur = resample(u,3,2);` means that `P=3` and `Q=2` which should resample the data `u` by `Q/P = 2/3` according to the documention. But the explanation under the example says: "Increase the sampling rate of data by a factor of 1.5 and compare the resampled and the original data signals." To get the sampling factor of 1.5 we should be doing   `P/Q` and not `Q/P` . Therefore, the explanation on how to mention the sampling factor is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to resample by a factor 2, and have access to the Signal Processing Toolbox, use [`resample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html):

```
y = resample(x,2,1);
```

If you are insistent on using `idresamp`, you need to know that it returns an object of type `iddata`, which comes with [a long documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/ident/ug/representing-time-and-frequency-domain-data-using-iddata-objects.html) on usage. I think this complicates things more than you are looking for. It seems you should be able to do:

```
x_resamp = idresamp(x,2);
y = x_resamp.OutputData;
```

(but I can't test this because I don't have access to this toolbox.)